# how to cast json to array in angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I have `file1.ts` which has a variable `menuGroups`

```
 menuGroups= Array();
```

i populate `menuGroups` with data so it looks something like this

[image: menuGroups]

i store this in localstorage : `localStorage.setItem("menuGroups", JSON.stringify(this.menuGroups));`

now in `file2.ts,` i want to assign above localstorage value to an array variable at class level. how to achieve it?

basically , in `file2.html`, i want to loop through the array `menuGroups` variable using `ngFor`.

i tried this in `file2.ts` but getting error

[image: file2.ts]

Comment: Maybe const menuGroups = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(‘menuGroups’)) ?

Comment: Edited question. but this does not work.

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? You put in a string of JSON, and parse it when you take it out.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. And what does not work? Any errors? If my suggestion is inside a separate file, you’ll need to export the const..

Comment: sorry if wasn't clear. i mean to say i want it in array so that i can loop it in ngFor. maybe i should rephrase my question.

Comment: Try using **deep-copy-ts**:   import `import { deepCopy } from 'deep-copy-ts';` and then `let stored = localStorage.getItem(key);` and finally `let item = deepCopy(stored);`  -  now ```item``` should have the structure you need. Same can be done using **lodash**.

Comment: Right - it looks like you have strict type checking switched on. JSON.parse expects a string, but your localStorage item could be null. Try JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem(‘menuGroups’)  || ‘’)

Comment: Even better - switch of strict mode in tsconfig..

Comment: @MikeOne, JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem(‘menuGroups’) || ‘’) worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
  menuGroups: any[] = [];

  populateNavBar() {
    this.menuGroups = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('menuGroups')) || [];
  }
```

[Working ex](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kvdtp5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to change

menuGroups: any;

Show run example stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rxvxzk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).